# no such table: operational error in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, auto-populate

I run makemigrations followed by migrate but still I get the error when I try to populate DB with dummy values that no such table exists. This happens for one single table. Here is my models.py file for the table:

```
class G(models.Model):
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=charLen256)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    add = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is what I try to do in my populate script:

```
def add_goal(item):
    g = G.objects.get_or_create(desc=item['description'], points=item['points_earned'])[0]
    g.save()
```

Can anybody spot the problem or error. I happen to have researched a lot but did not find any suggestion other than running makemigrations and migrate.

Here is the error:

```
  return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: myapp_goal
```

Comment: how many app do you have in your project, did you add  your `app` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Did you perhaps rename the model to `G` from `Goal` after you created your migrations? :)

Comment: The error is related to the `Goal` model but you've shared the `G` model. Can you share the `Goal` model or the generated migration file?